# Sql Query to show distinct records

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have a SQL query and  I am trying to display only distinct records like one post of each user order by latest post desc. How to do that? I tried group by and it failed.

```
SELECT jca.id,
ju.name,
jca.actor,
jca.title as title,
jca.created as postedDate
FROM community_activities jca 
left join users ju on jca.actor=ju.id
left join community_users jcu on jcu.userid=ju.id 
ORDER BY jca.id, jca.postedDate DESC LIMIT 0 , 50;


id  name    actor   title   
200     chandra 12      hello man
201     chandra 12      hey man
202     shayam  13      hello hero
203     chandra 12      hello yoyo
204     kokila  16      yep
205     chandra 12      hello y
206     chandra 12      hello  abc
```

Comment: These records are all distinct, where are you seeing dupes records?   You could use the DISTINCT keyword after the SELECT, but I don't see any dupes based on your sample data

Comment: As @Sparky says, they are already distinct. You have, for example, different titles for each user. If you want to show only one per use, which title do you want to show? The latest one? Or just any one...?

Comment: DISTINCT will not work in this case. It can be applied on one column for distinct values. If you are selecting multiple columns, it will return **DISTINCT ROWS**.

Comment: Names are not distinct in my above result set . I am trying to display one latest post of each user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display only the latest post of each user, create a derived table that consists of only the latest post id of each user and join `community_activities` to that table, so only those results will be displayed.

```
SELECT jca.id,
ju.name,
jca.actor,
jca.title as title,
jca.created as postedDate
FROM community_activities jca 

JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) max_id
FROM community_activities 
GROUP BY actor) t1 on t1.max_id = jca.id

LEFT JOIN users ju on jca.actor=ju.id
LEFT JOIN community_users jcu on jcu.userid=ju.id 
ORDER BY jca.id, jca.postedDate DESC LIMIT 0 , 50;
```

Comment: Result set is not sorted based on posted date. I think issue might be at jca.postedDate DESC

Comment: @Chandana is (author,created) unique or could there be multiple rows with the same (author,created)?

Comment: I am trying to show one record for one author. Author might post multiple post but only latest post by author should be shown.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    MAX(jca.id),     -- just selects maximum of each column , 
    DISTINCT ju.name, -- max() may be wrong for your scenario .
    MAX(jca.actor),
    MAX(jca.title) as title,
    MAX(jca.created) as postedDate
FROM 
    community_activities jca 
left join 
    users ju on jca.actor=ju.id
left join 
    community_users jcu on jcu.userid=ju.id 
GROUP BY 
    ju.name;
```

output:

```
202     shayam  13      hello hero

204     kokila  16      yep

206     chandra 12      hello  abc
```

Comment: It throws below error. You have an error in your SQL syntax near 'distinct ju.name,
    MAX(jca.actor),
    MAX(jca.title) as title,
    MAX(jca.c' at line 2

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT      jca.id,
            ju.name,
            jca.actor,
            jca.title AS title,
            MAX(jca.created) AS postedDate
FROM        community_activities jca 
LEFT JOIN   users ju ON (jca.actor = ju.id)
LEFT JOIN   community_users jcu ON (jcu.userid = ju.id)
ORDER BY    jca.created DESC
```

Comment: The above query displays only one latest row. I am trying to get one latest record(order by created) for each user.